# Orchid - Air roots growing at top of stem

Tags: orchids

My orchid grew 2 leaves about
Halfway up the stem and has since started growing air roots at the base of the leaves. The new leaves are extremely sticky as well. From what I’ve read on similar posts, this is a sign of a healthy plant and can be used to create a second Orchid by cutting and repotting.

My question is:

- Is this intact a sign of a healthy plant?
- If so, can this new leaf & air root growth be used to create a second plant?
- If so, is the “second plant” ready to be cut from the parent Orchid and pot up?
- Is there any risk to the Orchid if I decide to let it grow as is rather than cut the stem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your phalaenopsis orchid is very happy. This is a second plant indeed, called a [keiki](https://www.better-gro.com/orchid-blogs/what-is-an-orchid-keiki-how-do-i-care-for-it) (Hawaiian). The crowded pot may have forced mama to seek new territory for growth, like the air.

- Twist the baby off completely, or cut with a disposable blade.
- Pot up on its own in a small, perhaps 3" clay pot.
- Place in maximum light without sun, and water sparingly until you see leaf or root growth.

Your idea of leaving the baby on mama's flower stalk is novel. Your choice.